# Updating RouteTable in .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to create custom routing for contentpages for small CMS I'm building. I've always used a construction like the one below where I create a specific route with a unique identifier for each contentpage that exists in a database. This happens in startup.cs

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    page.Id.ToString(), // Unique route name
    page.Url.TrimStart('/'), // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPage", guid = page.Id } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This makes that I can do something like this in my controller

```cs
public ActionResult GetPage()
{
    Guid id = Guid.Parse(RouteData.Values["guid"].ToString());
    // content page?
    ContentPageModel model = pageService.GetPageById(id);
    return View("index", model);
}
```

Which is very handy in the case of (relatively) complex tree structures. I am now building something from the ground up where I want to use a similar construction again. The above works in .NET Core 5. However where I'm struggling is updating the routing table on save. If a page has a URL change I want to update the routing table. However, the `RouteTable` doesn't exist anymore and I can't find how to update the routes from my controller or service. This is what I'd used to do (sort of ;)

```cs
var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
// remove old route
var oldRoute = routes[routeItem.RouteName];
routes.Remove(oldRoute);
    
//add new route for page
routes.MapRoute(
  routeItem.RouteName, // Route name
  routeItem.Url, // URL with parameters
  new { controller = routeItem.Controller, action = routeItem.Action, guid = routeItem.RouteName } // Parameter defaults);
```

Comment: Please do not post a solution in the question. Post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

So I've solved this by using the `MapDynamicControllerRoute`:

```cs
endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<CmsRouteTransformer>("/{**slug}");
```

And then you can do something like:

```cs
public class CmsRouteTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{    
    public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        string url = string.Join("/", values.Values);
        var pageId = await _pageFinder.FindByUrl(url);
      
        if(pageId == null)
        {
            values["controller"] = "Home";
            values["action"] = "NotFound";
        }
        else
        {
            values["controller"] = "Home";
            values["action"] = "Page";
            values["guid"] = pageId;
        }
    
        return values;
    }
}
```

The `pageFinder` is just a service that has a mapping of slug/id that gets updated `onSave`.